# How to use JavaScript executor in playwright

Tags: javascript, ui-automation, playwright

Wanted to choice "Last Name" options from dropdown. tried with

```
await page.locator("text=Last Name").click();
```

So trying to implements JavaScript executor in playwrights.

"document.getElementsByClassName('ant-select-dropdown-menu-item')[21].click()"

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

tried with await page.evaluate(() => document.getElementsByClassName('ant-select-dropdown-menu-item')[21].click());

Still no hope.

My DOM is here

[image: 1]

Comment: Is the drop-down a `<select>` element or something else?

Comment: NO its not <select> attached my DOM in above.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to your DOM screenshot, the following should work as long as the drop down has been clicked and the options are visible:

```
await page.getByRole('option', { name: 'Last Name' }).click();
```

But I am wondering if the `unselectable='on'` against each `li` element is something to do with the issue here.

Comment: Looking for How to click using javaScript executor ?